# Containers that fill at least 100% of page height

Tags: html, css

How can the containers fill at least 100% of page height together, but no more than 100% if they fit?

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LoIlJu2qW5Y3dKNKmLe7?p=preview)

```
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  section {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
```

It looks fine if there is one `<section>` but not several:

```
    <section style="background: olive">Hi</section>
    <section style="background: tomato">Hello</section>
    <section style="background: olive">Hey</section>
```

Body content should fill at 100% of page height (so they would be ~33% each), and `min-height` is not an option here.

Usually page content is tall enough and doesn't need height style rules, but that's not the case if the section is alone on the page (and it depends on the resolution).

Background image can vary, I can't just make body color the same as the last section.

Can it be done with CSS alone?

Comment: The exact needs of this problem aren't very clear. Maybe you could reword your first sentence? It seems you want all of your containers to fill 100% of the page height and each container to have equal height. You want to maintain the equal heights and 100% of the page height regardless of how much content is in the container and regardless of how many containers there are, right?

Comment: @ Joseph I hoped that 'at least 100%' made the statement less ambiguous. I've got pages with multiple sections with a lot of content, they are fine without any extra styles. Some pages have a bit of content, so `body` background shows up at the bottom. That's the context of the problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, especially after you mentioned in my answer that you don't want scrollbars. Let me clean up the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the CSS table layout.

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ymzp46s/)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
section {
    display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<section style="background: olive">Hi</section>
<section style="background: tomato">Hello</section>
<section style="background: olive">Hey</section>
```

Comment: It looks promising. I've added Bootstrap navbar http://plnkr.co/edit/yoCFw1a4WEGdHSA5a0DW?p=preview , and it seems to steal the height from rows in Chrome (but is fine in FF and IE).

Comment: I wasn't too eager to flood the page with extra containers, but this one does the work for navbar indeed. Thank you!

Comment: @estus also check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/7ymzp46s/2/ (added 33.33% height to the table row, it works like min height for table layout).

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using flexbox and either viewport units or percentages to set a height on the body.

Note: Safari still needs a prefix.

Also note: I think all css solutions including both flexbox and table display will have a problem where the sections will be of unequal height once the content overflows the page height. The only thing I can think of to keep it looking acceptable is to give the sections a minimum height, such as `min-height: 20vh;` or `min-height: 200px;`.

---

This snippet shows how it will end up.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
section {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <section style="background: olive">Hi</section>
  <section style="background: tomato">Hello</section>
  <section style="background: olive">Hey</section>
</body>

</html>
```

---

This snippet shows how it will end up if the content of the containers stretches the containers past the full height of the page.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
section {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <section style="background: olive">Hi</section>
  <section style="background: tomato">Hello
    <p>Here<p>is<p>my<p>really<p>long<p>section<p>see<p>what<p>happens?
  </section>
  <section style="background: olive">Hey
    <p>This<p>section<p>is<p>really<p>long<p>too<p>!
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, same thing here http://plnkr.co/edit/DUcnRKsHYqrm07bO8V9D?p=preview I've tried flex, and it hasn't behaved properly with large containers.

Comment: @estus you're example looks great for me. What's wrong about it?

Comment: @estus you probably should add `overflow: scroll;` to the section style

Comment: But it would add scrollbars to each section instead of the page. [That plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUcnRKsHYqrm07bO8V9D?p=preview) provides proper scrolling only in FF37. IE11, GC42 and FF33 break the stuff, like this http://i58.tinypic.com/2eq6p2b.png .

Comment: Hmm. The tinypic didn't load. Try `overflow: auto;`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I misguided you but I wanted it to work similar to this one with extra container (both for large and small amount of content)  http://plnkr.co/edit/cdslkIKn0a8wWgBThNfU?p=preview But it makes me wonder if the same thing could be done with flexbox. Also `table-row` makes sections scale their sizes according to their content like table cells would do, it isn't a good thing (the second section makes significantly bigger with a couple of lines of content).

Comment: I think all of the answers using only css will have the problem of scaling sizes. When all the content fits on one page, they will be even sizes. When it doesn't fit they will start to not match. That is true of flexbox and of table-row. Right?

Comment: Not exactly, what I'm talking about is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYrHs0FJw5ApkoEyu9MK?p=preview), the middle row breaks 1/3 ratio when there is a bit more content than in adjacent rows. That's natural behaviour for table cells without explicit width/height (I cannot just specify 33% for them because there could be 2 or 4 of them). I hoped that flex could give more control on that while dealing with scrolling like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/cdslkIKn0a8wWgBThNfU?p=preview), I'm not really familiar with its capabilities beyond basics.

Answer (score 0):

You could try flexbox layout, but not all browser support this:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: How would you propose to use that? I've tried it http://plnkr.co/edit/FqZBMvH3Uy32S3GJlA8L?p=preview but had limited success (container content is overflowing).

Comment: Simply add `overflow: hidden;` to the container. (or `overflow: auto` if you want scrollbars). Other than that your example seems to do what you want.

Comment: P.S. You only need `-webkit-` flag: all browsers but Safari support flexbox with the native references (`flex: 1;` works in everything except Safari).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you want the body to have a maximum height of 100% of the viewport, and then you want however many sections there are to expand to fill the entire viewport?

The easy way to do this would be to tell the sections how many of them are there. For instance:

```html
<body class="three-sections">
```

or

```html
<section class="three-sections" style="background: olive">Hi</section>
<section class="three-sections" style="background: tomato">Hello</section>
<section class="three-sections" style="background: olive">Hey</section>
```

If you don't want to have to tell the page how many sections there are you could look up the [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), [:only-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child), and [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selectors. I don't know enough about your requirements to suggest something specific, but I think those are your best options.

As for making the height of the body at least the height of the page, you should look into [CSS viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). That should let you do what you want.

Comment: The requirements are quite tough (the sections are loaded with ajax), I'm trying to keep the solution as flexible as possible. As for viewport units, would they make real difference from percents in this case (sections are direct children of body)?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. Viewport units refer to the height of the browser window, whereas percent units refer to the height of the containing block (when used in the height property). Percent heights get super weird across browsers at the root level (when referring to or acting on the `<html>` or `<body>` elements). It's also worth noting that if it works at all, percentage heights based on the height of the `<html>` and `<body>` elements will refer to the height of the document and not the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry shared too soon, min height is not an option. Sorry for that.

You could change your min-height of the section to the percentage of 100/number of sections:

```
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  section {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 33%;
  }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asturias/Lx3sadtu/)

Comment: That's right, I understand that, but sections count may change dynamically, via ajax.

Comment: @estus then you will be most likely needing some javascript, unless the table layout solution from the above answer does it.